# How can I correctly calculate the direction for a moving object?

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

I'm solving the following problem: I have an object and I know its position now and its position 300ms ago. I assume the object is moving. I have a point to which I want the object to get.

What I need is to get the angle from my current object to the destination point in such a format that I know whether to turn left or right.

The idea is to assume the current angle from the last known position and the current position.

I'm trying to solve this in MATLAB. I've tried using several variations with `atan2` but either I get the wrong angle in some situations (like when my object is going in circles) or I get the wrong angle in all situations.

Examples of code that screws up:

```
a = new - old;
b = dest - new;
alpha = atan2(a(2) - b(2), a(1) - b(1);
```

where `new` is the current position (eg. `x = 40; y = 60; new = [x y];`), `old` is the 300ms old position and `dest` is the destination point.

### Edit

Here's a picture to demonstrate the problem with a few examples:

[image: Illustration of the problem]

In the above image there are a few points plotted and annotated. The black line indicates our estimated current facing of the object.

If the destination point is `dest1` I would expect an angle of about 88°.
If the destination point is `dest2` I would expect an angle of about 110°.
If the destination point is `dest3` I would expect an angle of about -80°.

Comment: Can you give us some example code that gets you the wrong angle in some situations?

Comment: Edited the question with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to note the scale on the sample graph you show above. The x-axis ticks move in steps of 1, and the y-axis ticks move in steps of 20. The picture with the two axes appropriately scaled (like with the command [`axis equal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/axis.html)) would be a lot narrower than you have, so the angles you expect to get are not right. The expected angles will be close to right angles, just a few degrees off from 90 degrees.

The equation [Nathan derives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209360/correctly-calculating-direction-for-moving-object/4209481#4209481) is valid for column vector inputs `a` and `b`:

```
theta = acos(a'*b/(sqrt(a'*a) * sqrt(b'*b)));
```

If you want to change this equation to work with row vectors, you would have to switch the transpose operator in both the calculation of the dot product as well as the norms, like so:

```
theta = acos(a*b'/(sqrt(a*a') * sqrt(b*b')));
```

As an alternative, you could just use the functions [DOT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dot.html) and [NORM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/norm.html):

```
theta = acos(dot(a,b)/(norm(a)*norm(b)));
```

Finally, you have to account for the direction, i.e. whether the angle should be positive (turn clockwise) or negative (turn counter-clockwise). You can do this by computing the sign of the z component for the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of `b` and `a`. If it's positive, the angle should be positive. If it's negative, the angle should be negative. Using the function [SIGN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sign.html), our new equation becomes:

```
theta = sign(b(1)*a(2)-b(2)*a(1)) * acos(dot(a,b)/(norm(a)*norm(b)));
```

For your examples, the above equation gives an angle of 88.85, 92.15, and -88.57 for your three points `dest1`, `dest2`, and `dest3`.

**NOTE:** One special case you will need to be aware of is if your object is moving *directly* away from the destination point, i.e. if the angle between `a` and `b` is 180 degrees. In such a case you will have to pick an arbitrary turn direction (left or right) and a number of degrees to turn (180 would be ideal ;) ). Here's one way you could account for this condition using the function [EPS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eps.html):

```
theta = acos(dot(a,b)/(norm(a)*norm(b)));   %# Compute theta
if abs(theta-pi) < eps  %# Check if theta is within some tolerance of pi
  %# Pick your own turn direction and amount here
else
  theta = sign(b(1)*a(2)-b(2)*a(1))*theta;  %# Find turn direction
end
```

Comment: The angle seems to be calculated correctly, however the sign is not. My test is with `new = [10 10]; old = [8 9.5]; dest = [15 20];` which yields an angle of 49.3987&deg;. However the target is to the left of the heading in this case and so should be negative. Nice answer, though.

Comment: @Jakub: Did you try the code in the newest version of my answer? I changed how I computed the direction so now it uses cross-products, and this gives me the correct answer of -49.3987 for your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the dot-product of the vectors.

Define the vectors 'a' and 'b' as:

```
a = new - old;
b = dest - new;
```

and use the fact that the dot product is:

```
a dot b = norm2(a) * norm2(b) * cos(theta)
```

where `theta` is the angle between two vectors, and you get:

```
cos(theta) = (a dot b)/ (norm2(a) * norm2(b))
```

The best way to calculate `a dot b`, assuming they are column vectors, is like this:

```
a_dot_b = a'*b;
```

and:

```
norm2(a) = sqrt(a'*a);
```

so you get:

```
cos(theta) = a'*b/(sqrt((a'*a)) * sqrt((b'*b)))
```

Depending on the sign of the cosine you either go left or right

Comment: So to get the angle I use (since my positions are row vectors) `alpha = acos(a*b'/((a'*a) * (b'*b)))`? I tried and the angle isn't correct...

Comment: More specifically the angle seems to be 90deg more then we need or NaN.

Comment: You're missing a `sqrt` in your calculation of the norms.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you have a line defined by the points `old` and `new` and wish to determine if `dest` is on right or the left of that line? In which case have a look at this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560492/how-to-tell-wether-a-point-is-right-or-left-of-a-line).