# Determine if two points are on the same side of a line in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, lines, points, hittest

Suppose I have two points representing a line A, such as:

```
var A = [ { x: 385, y: 380 }, { x: 420, y: 400 }]
```

And I have two other points B and C such as:

```
var B = { x: 385, y: 420 }
var C = { x: 405, y: 423 }
```

How would I determine if B and C are both on the same side of line A? To add a little context, I am trying to do hit testing for a hexagon, where B is the center point of the hexagon, C is the current mouse position and A is each line of the hexagon. All of these points are essentially pixel coordinates where 0,0 is the upper left hand corner.

I don't need this to be blazing fast I am just trying to create the simplest possible hexagon hit test algorithm I can. My theory is that if I can determine that C is on the same side of each line of the hexagon as B then the hit test is successful. I have read several mathematical algorithms for doing this but they always seem to be in a different type of coordinate system and I'm struggling to translate it into something usable in javascript.

**EDIT:** here is my actual Hexagon function given the answer below. The answer to this question is in the update function.

```
var TILE_WIDTH = 70
var TILE_HEIGHT = 80

function Hexagon(x, y) {
    var normalColor = 'rgb(207, 226, 243)'
    var hilightColor = 'rgb(204, 204, 204)'
    var currentColor = normalColor

    var coords = new TileCoordinates(x, y)
    var points = [
        { x: coords.x, y: coords.y - TILE_HEIGHT / 2 },
        { x: coords.x + TILE_WIDTH / 2, y: coords.y - TILE_HEIGHT / 4 },
        { x: coords.x + TILE_WIDTH / 2, y: coords.y + TILE_HEIGHT / 4 },
        { x: coords.x, y: coords.y + TILE_HEIGHT / 2 },
        { x: coords.x - TILE_WIDTH / 2, y: coords.y + TILE_HEIGHT / 4 },
        { x: coords.x - TILE_WIDTH / 2, y: coords.y - TILE_HEIGHT / 4 },
    ]

    var sides = [
        [points[0], points[1]],
        [points[1], points[2]],
        [points[2], points[3]],
        [points[3], points[4]],
        [points[4], points[5]],
        [points[5], points[0]]
    ]

    this.update = function (totalTime, updateTime) {

        var B = coords
        var C = Mouse.state
        var inside = C != null
        if (inside) {
            for (i in sides) {
                var A = sides[i]
                var w = { y: A[1].x - A[0].x, x: -(A[1].y - A[0].y) }
                var P = A[1]

                inside = ((B.x - P.x) * w.x + (B.y - P.y) * w.y) * ((C.x - P.x) * w.x + (C.y - P.y) * w.y) > 0
                if (!inside) break
            }
        }

        if (inside)
            currentColor = hilightColor
        else
            currentColor = normalColor
    }

    this.draw = function (ctx) {
        ctx.fillStyle = currentColor
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(11, 83, 148)'
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y)
        ctx.lineTo(points[1].x, points[1].y)
        ctx.lineTo(points[2].x, points[2].y)
        ctx.lineTo(points[3].x, points[3].y)
        ctx.lineTo(points[4].x, points[4].y)
        ctx.lineTo(points[5].x, points[5].y)
        ctx.lineTo(points[0].x, points[0].y)
        ctx.fill()
        ctx.stroke()

        ctx.fillStyle = '#000'
        var text = coords.pos_x + ',' + coords.pos_y
        var measure = ctx.measureText(text)
        ctx.fillText(text, coords.x - measure.width / 2, coords.y + 12 + (TILE_HEIGHT / 4))
    }
}

// this is in a separate function because other objects that render into the hex
// need the pixel coordinates of the tile also
function TileCoordinates(x, y) {
    this.pos_x = x
    this.pos_y = y
    this.x = x * TILE_WIDTH + ((y + 1) * TILE_WIDTH / 2)
    this.y = (y + 1) * (3 / 4 * TILE_HEIGHT)
}
```

To determine same-sidedness I multiplied the results of B and C and if the result is > 0 then they are either both positive or both negative. I'm rendering and updating the hexagon into a canvas on a loop using setInterval.

Comment: If you aren't going to post an algorithm you've chosen, at least post some links to those you've found. Off the top of my head, if the line is AB and the points are C and D, then if the angles ABD and ABC are either both greater than 180 or both less than 180, D and C are "on the same side".

Comment: Not exactly answering your question, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test has some good answers for polygon hit testing in general.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell wether a point is right or left of a line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560492/how-to-tell-wether-a-point-is-right-or-left-of-a-line)

Comment: Yes, I think thats pretty close. Though I was specifically trying to put it into javascript terms and in a way I could understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line representing A is described by the vector `v = { x: 420 - 385, y: 400 - 380 } = { x: 35, y: 20 }` and the starting point `P = { x: 385, y: 380 }`.  Given a vector `(x, y)` in 2d, the vector `(y, -x)` is always at right angles to it.  So the vector `w = { x: 20, y: -35 }` is at right angles to `v`.  Linear algebra tells us that the sign of `(B - P) dot w` tells us which side of the line you are on where `dot` is the standard dot product.  (The line itself is at zero.)

Therefore in your example the calculation we need to do is this:

```
For B:
(B - P) dot w
  = { x: 385 - 385, y: 420 - 380 } dot { x: 20, y: -35 }
  = { x: 0, y: 40} dot { x: 20, y: -35 }
  = (0 * 20) + (40 * (-35))
  = -1400

For C:
(C - P dot w
  = { x: 405 - 385, y: 423 - 380 } dot { x: 20, y: -35 }
  = { x: 20, y: 43} dot { x: 20, y: -35 }
  = (20 * 20) + (43 * (-35))
  = -1105
```

Since the sign is the same, they are on the same side.

In fact we can say more.  If you are at the starting point of `A` and are facing the ending point, both points will be on your left hand side.  (The left side will be negative, the right side will be positive.)

Comment: Beautiful, the OP just needs to program for the general case. Having a surveying background, I solved it using angles, but your solution is much more elegant. I hope you don't mind if I pinch your algorithm - full attribution of course. :-)

Comment: Oh, one extra thing - the OP really should test if either point is on the line (or extremely close given the small inaccuracies in ECMAScript numbers) and make a decision about what that means. If one point is on the line, should the result be that they are both on the same side, not on the same side, or undefined?

Comment: @RobG - Feel free to pinch it with no attribution.  It is a standard technique. :-)

Comment: works like a charm! I will update my original post with my actual Hexagon function now.

Comment: I don't know how this can work for you.  Should be the cross product, not the dot product! (A x B = a1*b2 - a2*b1)  I had a large field of over 200 non-overlapping triangles, and tested 30 points.  Using the dot product, the points were all in multiple triangles; using the cross product, each point was found in a single triangle.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the correction!  I didn't look at my code carefully enough - it IS the dot product of two cross products.  Should I delete my mistaken comment?

Comment: Sure.  You delete yours and I'll delete mine.