# Finding distance of imaginary point

Tags: javascript, math, fabricjs, trigonometry

I have all coordinates but Px, and I need to find the distance between Px and the Mouse Location(red line). It will be implemented on javascript, any ideas?

[image]

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html with the assumption you mean perpendicular distance

Comment: yes, also assuming that the mouse can be anywhere else, on both sides of the blue line

Comment: answer is listed right in the linked page. scroll down to 'line defined by two points'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
var P1 = {x: 10, y: 5},
    P2 = {x: 8,  y: 4},
    PM = {x: 2,  y: 5};

function distance(source, target1, target2) {
    var zaehler = Math.abs((target2.x - target1.x)*(target1.y - source.y) - (target1.x - source.x)*(target2.y - target1.y));
    var nenner = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(target2.x - target1.x, 2) + Math.pow(target2.y - target1.y, 2));
    return zaehler/nenner;
}

console.log(distance(PM, P2, P1) === distance(PM, P1, P2));
```

Comment: I'm confused with distance's parameters, but I think I know what you meant

Comment: thank you so much, extra small question, can I tell whenever the mouse crosses the blue line?

Comment: answering my previous question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560492/how-to-tell-whether-a-point-is-to-the-right-or-left-side-of-a-line