# Point inside a Polygon (Teradata Geospatial SQL)

Tags: sql, polygon, geospatial, teradata

I have tried search on the web, but unable to find an answer.
I could use Teradata SQL to draw a square polygon:
`New ST_GEOMETRY('Polygon((150 -35, 150 -34, 149 -34, 149 -35))') As Region1`
and create a point: `New ST_GEOMETRY('Point(149.5 -34.5)') As Location1`

Is there a way to check if the point "Location1" is inside the polygon "Region1"?

Also if Region2, which is inside Region1, is to be exclude
`New ST_GEOMETRY('Polygon((149.75 -34.25, 149.75 -34.75, 149.25 -34.75, 149.25 -34.25))') As Region2`
What is the method (Teradata SQL) to create a polygon/shape "Region3", which is "Region1" exclude "Region2"?

Thanks

Comment: [relevant[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853481/is-point-inside-polygon)

Comment: Teradata supports Open Geospatial Consortium Simple Features specification. Consider using `ST_CONTAINS()` predicate and `ST_DIFFERENCE()` method.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**

As Dmitri Chubarov mentions, you can use `ST_CONTAINS`. See the code below for a working example.

For the polygon to work the polygon should be "closed" with the first and last point of the polygon being identical.

**Working Example Tested with Teradata 16**

The code below creates:

1. A table with points
2. A table with polygons
3. A select statement with a combination off all points and polygons, and an indicator of the point is in the polygon

**SQL**

```
---------- 1. Create points ----------

-- DROP TABLE SAMPLE_POINTS;
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE SAMPLE_POINTS (SKEY INTEGER, POINT ST_GEOMETRY) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
INSERT INTO SAMPLE_POINTS VALUES (1, Cast('Point(149.5 -34.5)' AS ST_GEOMETRY));
INSERT INTO SAMPLE_POINTS VALUES (2, Cast('Point(1 1)' AS ST_GEOMETRY));

---------- 2. Create polygons ----------

-- DROP TABLE SAMPLE_POLYGONS;
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE SAMPLE_POLYGONS (SKEY INTEGER, POLYGON ST_GEOMETRY) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
INSERT INTO SAMPLE_POLYGONS VALUES (1, Cast('Polygon((150 -35, 150 -34, 149 -34, 149 -35))' AS ST_GEOMETRY));
INSERT INTO SAMPLE_POLYGONS VALUES (2, Cast('Polygon((150 -35, 150 -34, 149 -34, 149 -35, 150 -35))' AS ST_GEOMETRY));
INSERT INTO SAMPLE_POLYGONS VALUES (3, Cast('POLYGON((0 0, 0 2, 2 2, 2 0, 0 0))' AS ST_GEOMETRY));
INSERT INTO SAMPLE_POLYGONS VALUES (4, Cast('POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))' AS ST_GEOMETRY));

---------- 3. Point in polygon indicator ----------

SELECT
  POI.SKEY                             AS POINT_KEY
  , Cast(POI.POINT AS VARCHAR(255))    AS POINT
  , POL.SKEY                           AS POLYGON_KEY
  , Cast(POL.POLYGON AS VARCHAR(255))  AS POLYGON
  , POL.POLYGON.ST_Contains(POI.POINT) AS PIP_IND
FROM SAMPLE_POLYGONS AS POL
     , SAMPLE_POINTS AS POI
;
```

**Output**

| POINT_KEY | POINT | POLYGON_KEY | POLYGON | PIP_IND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | POINT (149.5 -34.5) | 4 | POLYGON ((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0)) | 0 |
| 1 | POINT (149.5 -34.5) | 2 | POLYGON ((150 -35,150 -34,149 -34,149 -35,150 -35)) | 1 |
| 1 | POINT (149.5 -34.5) | 3 | POLYGON ((0 0,0 2,2 2,2 0,0 0)) | 0 |
| 1 | POINT (149.5 -34.5) | 1 | POLYGON ((150 -35,150 -34,149 -34,149 -35)) | 0 |
| 2 | POINT (1 1) | 4 | POLYGON ((0 0,0 1,1 1,1 0,0 0)) | 0 |
| 2 | POINT (1 1) | 2 | POLYGON ((150 -35,150 -34,149 -34,149 -35,150 -35)) | 0 |
| 2 | POINT (1 1) | 3 | POLYGON ((0 0,0 2,2 2,2 0,0 0)) | 1 |
| 2 | POINT (1 1) | 1 | POLYGON ((150 -35,150 -34,149 -34,149 -35)) | 0 |

Please note:

- Closed polygon: The initial polygon 1 was not working because the polygon needs to be closed by repeating the first point. Polygon 2 is the corrected version.
- Edge case: Point 2 is on the edge of polygon 4 and therefore is not marked as being in the polygon.

Source:

- [https://docs.teradata.com/r/bbnDyCxlS~Mtf8vF_Sz3mw/U8RD1RdT3seozM3B_qz1ZA](https://docs.teradata.com/r/bbnDyCxlS%7EMtf8vF_Sz3mw/U8RD1RdT3seozM3B_qz1ZA)
- https://docs.teradata.com/r/W1AEeHO2cxTi3Sn7dtj8hg/ZoeJVcESAd5ysyoYM4O4Wg