# How to determine the side a point sits from a line in 3D

Tags: c#, math, geometry

I've found a bunch of answers to determining which side a point lays between a line, but only in 2D.

Here's an existing question of what I want, but it 2D: [How to tell whether a point is to the right or left side of a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560492/how-to-tell-whether-a-point-is-to-the-right-or-left-side-of-a-line/1560510)

How do I adapt the formula below that is currently only taking into account the X, Y positions, to also take into account the Z axis? Assuming the view point is top-down.

```
position = sign((Bx - Ax) * (Y - Ay) - (By - Ay) * (X - Ax))
```

Comment: you sure in 3d you don't mean which side of a plane you are on?

Comment: There's an infinite number of solutions because you could view the line from any angle. You'd need to at least define what you mean by "side" (from which point of view?)

Comment: That's quite a glaring omission I made - due to the fact I didn't even think about it. The view point will be top-down,

Comment: @AquaGeneral in which case, just ignore z entirely (or y, or whichever axis you use for 'down') and only use the x/y coords from your points :)

Comment: @LukeBriggs I can't believe (well I can actually) that I didn't think it through like that. Thanks!

Comment: @AquaGeneral no problem - I'll drop it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line in 3D can be viewed from any angle, so in order to pick 'sides' you first have to pick an axis that you'll view it from. Lets say we're viewing it on the Y axis looking straight down, and our line consists of these two points:

> (1,4,5) -> (5,2,6)

As we're looking along that Y axis, we can just completely ignore the Y coordinates and treat the line as if it was simply this:

> (1,0,5) -> (5,0,6)

Then perform a 2D sign test like any other, only using x/z here.

If your viewer isn't axis aligned then you'd just need to project your line into "screen space" by multiplying the points by your view matrix (implementation of which varies by use case). You'd then end up with a line that is typically being viewed along the Z axis so you can then safely ignore it.