# SQL spatial determine which side of a line a point is on

Tags: sql, geospatial, spatial, spatial-query

I have a line and a series of points as geometry objects in SQL spatial. I would like to determine which side of the line each point falls on. The line represents a coastline - so some points are in the ocean, and others are on the land. Is this possible?

[image: The problem]

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: You can use a Cross Product... This is easy to find, for example these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560492/how-to-tell-whether-a-point-is-to-the-right-or-left-side-of-a-line