# don't let one square go beyond the second square

Tags: javascript, rotation, geometry, draggable, square

I have 2 squares and all positions 
for rotated square

```
sq1.x1y1
sq1.x2y2
sq1.x3y3
sq1.x4y4 
sq1.maxX
sq1.minX
sq1.maxY
sq1.minY
sq1.rotatedAngl
sq1.cX
sq1.cY
```

all positions before rotation

and for second square

```
sq2.x1y1
sq2.x2y2
sq2.x3y3
sq2.x4y4 
sq2.maxX
sq2.minX
sq2.maxY
sq2.minY
sq2.cX
sq2.cY
```

This is my squares

[image]

After dragging square 1 and stop

[image]

After Rotate 45 deg

[image]

And after drag square 1

[image]

i want stop dragging when the corners square 2 intersect to square 1

Answer (score 1):

You have the coordinates of every corner. You can define segments by two corners.
You can get the distance from one corner (square to drag) to the segments of the other square.

The distance formula, and its sign, can be as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560510/3871028)

You may compare signs for two parallel sides of a square. If both are "at left" or both are "right" then the point is outside of the square.

Answer (score 1):

A square can be defined as the triple `{center1, side, angle}` where `center = {double center.x, double center.y}` is the center of the square, `double side` is the length of the side of the square, and finally `double angle` is the angle to which the square is rotated from the horizontal direction.

Given the two squares, you can represent them as
`square1 = {center1, side1, angle1}` and `square2 = {center2, side2, angle2}`. The idea for an algorithm is:

**Step 1:** rotate `square2` by angle `- angle1` so that its sides are parallel to the coordinate axes, as in your first example. Obtain the new

```
square1 ---> sqare10 = {center1, side1, 0}
```

**Step 2:** rotate `square2` also by angle `- angle1`. Obtain the new square

```
square2 ---> sqare20 = {center2, side2, angle2 - angle1}
```

**Step 3:** introduce the new square `square30 = {center2, side3, 0}` so that this new square is the smallest square that contains `sqare20` and its sides are parallel to the coordinate axes (the four vertices of `square20` lie on the edges of `square30` and the two of them share the same center). Square30's side-length is calculated as

```
side3 = side2 * (cos(angle2 - angle1) + sin(angle2 - angle1))
```

**Step 4:** Now you are in the situation of your first example where the pair of squares 
`square10` and `square30` have edges parallel to the coordinate axes. Check the relative position of these two squares:  `square10` and `square30`:

- if `square30` is completely inside `square10` then the original `square2` is completely inside the original `square1`
- else if `square30` has an edge that touches an edge of `square10`, then the original `square2` has a vertex that touches on of the sides of the original  `square1`