# Finding the new relative position of a point against the line after moved together

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization

I am working on a drawing application. I summerize the main question to a tiny scenario:

User draws the line A1-B1 and also the point M1. Now user moves the line A1-B1 to a new position A2-B2 while the point M1 also should move with the line (like a rigid body). How can I calculate the new position of point M2?

[image]

I know it is possbile with complex calucations on lines or circles conjuction and finally detemrining if the new point is on the right or left of line ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560492/how-to-tell-whether-a-point-is-to-the-right-or-left-side-of-a-line)) etc. But as I want to recalculate live on any steps of dragging, I guess there should be a shortcut and light solution which all modeling softwares use. Is there really a shortcut formula rahter than the line or circle conjuctions?

To summerize the problem again I am looking for a light function with given A1,B1,A2,B2,M1 and looking for M2 position (two separate formula for x and y)

`M2 = f(A1,B1,A2,B2,M1)`

**My guess:** I think finding the center and the angle of rotation is one of the best options but I don't know again if there is a shotcut function to find them.

**Edit:** I prefer to implement it in an online website, so if there is a ready javascript library, it would be helpful, However I am now just looking for the mathematical logic.

Comment: The library used may favor certain approaches over others. Maybe you want to specify the language/library?

Comment: I prefer JavaScript (added to question) thanks. @Mr.T

Comment: Are you comfortable with vector arithmetic and dot products?

Comment: It sounds good. I am mathematician and open to any light weight solution @Beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with **A<sub>1</sub>** and **B<sub>1</sub>**.

**D** = **B<sub>1</sub>** - **A<sub>1</sub>**
**C<sub>1</sub>** = **D**/|**D**|

Rotate **C<sub>1</sub>** 90 degrees counter-clockwise to get **C'<sub>1</sub>**:
**C<sub>1</sub>** = (cx, cy)
**C'<sub>1</sub>** = (-cy, cx)

Now take **M<sub>1</sub>** - **A<sub>1</sub>** and measure it against **C<sub>1</sub>** and **C'<sub>1</sub>**:

j = (**M<sub>1</sub>** - **A**) **·** **C<sub>1</sub>**
k = (**M<sub>1</sub>** - **A**) **·** **C'<sub>1</sub>**

Now it's easy to prove:

**M<sub>1</sub>** = **A<sub>1</sub>** + j **C<sub>1</sub>** + k **C'<sub>1</sub>**

So j and k tell you where **M<sub>1</sub>** is, given **A<sub>1</sub>** and **B<sub>1</sub>**.

When you get **A<sub>2</sub>** and **B<sub>2</sub>**, use them to construct **C<sub>2</sub>**, rotate it to get **C'<sub>2</sub>**, and then you'll have:

**M<sub>2</sub>** = **A<sub>2</sub>** + j **C<sub>2</sub>** + k **C'<sub>2</sub>**

Comment: For A1(0,0), B1(1,1), M1(1,-1) the J and K are 0 . Is there a problem in `M1 = A1 + j C1 + k C'1`

Comment: @AliSheikhpour: I forgot to normalise **C**, and you made an arithmetical error. I'll edit my answer. A1=(0,0), B1=(1,1), M1=(1,-1), D=(1,1), C1=(1/sqrt(2),1/sqrt(2)), C'1=(-1/sqrt(2),1/sqrt(2)), J=0, K=-sqrt(2)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming points are objects which have x and y values. Like this:

```
A1 = {x: 100, y:100}
```

Here's a lightweight solution:

```
function reposition(A1,A2,B1,B2,M1)
    {
 //Getting the Angle Between Lines
    var angle = Math.atan2(B2.y-B1.y, B2.x-B1.x)-Math.atan2(A2.y-A1.y, A2.x-A1.x);
 //Rotating the point
    var xdif = M1.x-A1.x; //point.x-origin.x
    var ydif = M1.y-A1.y; //point.y-origin.y
 //Returning M2
    return {x:B1.x + Math.cos(angle) * xdif - Math.sin(angle) * ydif, y: B1.y + Math.sin(angle) * xdif + Math.cos(angle) * ydif}
    }
```