# Get direction of arrow according to watched point

Tags: java, math, position, spigot

I want to get an arrow from the point with the direction to another point.

Before begin, I'm using this method to get the arrow according to the yaw:

```java
public static String getArrow(double yaw) {
    if (22.50 < yaw && yaw < 67.50) return "⬉";
    else if (67.50 < yaw && yaw < 112.5) return "⬅";
    else if (112.50 < yaw && yaw < 157.5) return "⬋";
    else if (157.50 < yaw && yaw < 202.5) return "⬇";
    else if (202.50 < yaw && yaw < 247.5) return "⬊";
    else if (247.50 < yaw && yaw < 292.5) return "➡";
    else if (292.50 < yaw && yaw < 337.5)
        return "⬈";
    return "⬆";
}
```

I started by using a method like that:

```java
public static String getArrowTo(Location position, Vector direction, Location watched) {
    Vector a = watched.clone().subtract(position).toVector().normalize();
    double angle = Math.acos(a.dot(direction));
    return getArrow(Math.toDegrees(angle));
}
```

But each time that the point was on left, the arrow show the forward arrow. So, I made something when it's on left, but it's not fixed even with this trick. Actually I'm using:

```java
public static String getArrowTo(Location position, Vector direction, Location watched) {
    Vector a = watched.clone().subtract(position).toVector().normalize();
    double angle = Math.acos(a.dot(direction));
    if (isLeft(position, position.clone().add(direction), watched.toVector()))
        angle = 360 - angle;
    return getArrow(Math.toDegrees(angle));
}

public static boolean isLeft(Location a, Location b, Vector c) {
    return ((b.getX() - a.getX()) * (c.getZ() - a.getZ()) - (b.getZ() - a.getZ()) * (c.getX() - a.getX())) > 0;
}
```

The `isLeft` method comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3461533/10952503).

PS: the class used are [`Location`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Location.html) and [`Vector`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/util/Vector.html), here showed for spigot 1.19 but I'm using 1.8.8.

The left method seems to don't enough work in my case (I don't know why). By adding `angle = angle < 0 ? (360 + angle) : angle` it should works better but it never goes below 0. It's always in 0-180 range.

I tested the MBo solution: it find the right, but that's all. The front is something known as back, the right is also on the left etc..

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Have you tried `atan2` function? (returns range -pi..pi, so you need to correct negative values adding 2*pi)

Comment: @MBo do you mean `atan` ? Because atan2 require 2 arguments

Comment: No, I mean namely atan2, two arguments are differences by x and y

Comment: So instead of `acos` I should make mulitplication of x then z to use then in atan2 ?

Comment: @MBo using `double angle = Math.atan2(a.getX() * direction.getX(), a.getZ() * direction.getZ());` doesn't work properly, it seems to just inverse the issue (the left works, not the right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Location playerLocation = player.getLocation();

Vector locVector = location.toVector().subtract(playerLocation.toVector());

String direction = null;

double locAngle = Math.atan2(locVector.getZ(), locVector.getX());
double playerAngle = Math.atan2(playerLocation.getDirection().getZ(), playerLocation.getDirection().getX());

double angle = playerAngle - locAngle;

while (angle > Math.PI) {
    angle = angle - 2 * Math.PI;
}

while (angle < -Math.PI) {
    angle = angle + 2 * Math.PI;
}

if (angle < -2.749 || angle >= 2.749) { // -7/8 pi
    direction = "⬇";
} else if (angle < -1.963) { // -5/8 pi
    direction = "⬊";
} else if (angle < -1.178) { // -3/8 pi
    direction = "➡";
} else if (angle < -0.393) { // -1/8 pi
    direction = "⬈";
} else if (angle < 0.393) { // 1/8 pi
    direction = "⬆";
} else if (angle < 1.178) { // 3/8 pi
    direction = "⬉";
} else if (angle < 1.963) { // 5/8 p
    direction = "⬅";
} else if (angle < 2.749) { // 7/8 pi
    direction = "⬋";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For two point `a` and `b` you can find direction angle `a->b` as

```
double angle = Math.atan2(b.getZ()-a.getZ(), b.getX()-a.getX());
if (angle<0)
   angle += 2*Math.Pi;
```

result is in radians in range `-Pi..Pi`, so you can adapt result to `0..2*Pi` range

Comment: @Elikill58 Is this what you want? (I'm tangled a bit with your three Location parameters, so gave the simplest variant for two points)

Comment: I'm actually checking. And it's clearly better (thanks) just now the left is actually at the oppose, like everytime I pass the left, instead of showing forward, it show backward (right: 0.01, left: 179.9)