# Testing whether a polygon is simple or complex

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

For a polygon defined as a sequence of (x,y) points, how can I detect whether it is complex or not?  A complex polygon has intersections with itself, as shown:

[image: example complex polygon image]

Is there a better solution than checking every pair which would have a time complexity of O(N<sup>2</sup>)?

Comment: Well, if polygon is entered by user with gmaps, then you're not likely to have more than 100 vertexes. In this case, I would go with simple solution first and see if it's enough.

Comment: @Nikita, the question may have been misleading in that regard. The user can also edit an existing polygon with thousands of vertices.  Regardless, I'm still interested to know the best approach for this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are sweep methods which can determine this much faster than a brute force approach.  In addition, they can be used to break a non-simple polygon into multiple simple polygons.

For details, see [this article](http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0108/algorithm_0108.htm), in particular, this [code to test for a simple polygon](https://web.archive.org/web/20060613060645/http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0108/algorithm_0108.htm#Test%20if%20Simple).

Comment: The code link is http://geomalgorithms.com/a09-_intersect-3.html#simple_Polygon() the auto-escaped version from markdown doesn't work.

Comment: Links are broken. This answer doesn't have any information other than "there exists an algorithm that does this." This is why it's important for answers to be self-contained. :(

Answer (score 5):

See [Bentley Ottmann Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) for a sweep based O((N + I)log N) method for this.
Where N is the number of line segments and I is number of intersection points.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, this can be done in linear time use Chazelle's triangulation algorithm. It either triangulates the polygon or find out the polygon is not simple.

Comment: Except there are precious few if any practical implementations of Chazelle's due to its complexity to implement.