# how can I get if a QPolygon is simple?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-quick, qpainterpath, qpolygon

I am coding a tool that enables to draw polygons.
I want them to be simple polygons and forbid drawing complex polygons.

I have tried ToSubpathPolygons()

I have the list of QPoints that form the polygon.

I am coding in c++ + Qt. I think I could try with segment intersections and if there is an intersection it is not simple.

I thought qpainterpath tosubpathPolygons should give me more than one if it is a complex polygon.
The problem should be something like this:

```
if(q.toSubpathPolygons().length()==1)
{
//whatever
}
else{
    cout<<"not a polygon"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "this function doesn't seem to work properly"? often thinking the problem is somewhere else but not in your code just makes it harder to solve it. Rather unlikely that it is broken and noone noticed before, no? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: That is not the problem, i have tried to subpathpolygons but I think this is not the way to solve the problem

Comment: Your question is not clear, you could ask something concrete.

Comment: What is a simple polygon?

Comment: https://www.google.es/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjHzq3d3sLTAhUFORoKHe1vCxAQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.personal.kent.edu%2F~rmuhamma%2FCompgeometry%2FMyCG%2FDefinitions%2Fdefinition.htm&psig=AFQjCNEXpCkeHPq2a0FPpGoq5Fp2iHZ_rQ&ust=1493317332606474

Comment: if thats not the problem, then what is the problem? simply follow the definition and check if any of the lines intersect

Comment: How can I know if any of them intersect?

Comment: @P.Perez, I can suggest linear algorithm, which can check whether polygon (with one countour) is simple. Is this sufficient for you?

Comment: I think that would be perfect

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001745/testing-whether-a-polygon-is-simple-or-complex