# area contained in a piecewise straight simply closed curve

Tags: algorithm

I have the plane points pi i=1,...,n and they form a simply closed but not necessarily convex curve. The curve from pi to p(i+1) and from pn to p1 is the straight line. I need an algorithm to compute the area contained.

Comment: [wikipedia Polygon Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon#Area)

Comment: For simple, non-intersecting polygons (convex or non-convex) the simplest method to calculate area is explained very well [here](https://alienryderflex.com/polygon_area/). This is known as the [Shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula)

Comment: @Ripi2 has given you a (fairly) simple way to calculate it using an equation. If that is allowed, that is *much* simpler than any algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

Let us break down the problem into much smaller, manageable ones.

**The idea:**
Break it down into triangles and sum their area.
In every iteration get a point that is convex (in relation to the one before and after), get the area of that triangle (`area(p(i), p(i-1), p(i+1))`) and remove that point from the list of relevant point still to be handled.

On the topic of checking if a point is inside a convex polygon, I'll assume the points are going clockwise (if not, reverse them of swap the condition on the angle). Basically, given `p(i), p(j), p(k)` where `i + 1 = j` and `j + 1 = k` (consecutive), the angle between the ledges `edge(i, j)` and `edge(j, k)` will tell us if `p(j)` is concave or convex. This solution can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/472001/3045171)

```
totlaArea = 0
listOfPoints = inputtedPoints

getThreeAdjacentPoints(listOfPoints, index) {
  n = listOfPoints.length
  point1 = listOfPoints[pointIndex]
  point2 = listOfPoints[(pointIndex + 1) % n]
  point3 = listOfPoints[(pointIndex - 1) % n]
  return { point1, point2, point3 }
}

getTriangleArea(listOfPoints, index) {
  { point1, point2, point3 } = getThreeAdjacentPoints(listOfPoints, index)
  return calculateTriangleArea(point1, point2, point3)
}

getNextConvexPointIndex(listOfPoints) {
  for index in listOfPoints.length - 1:
    { point1, point2, point3 } = getThreeAdjacentPoints(listOfPoints, index)
    angleBetweenEdges = getAngle(edge(point3, point1), edge(point1, point2))
    if angleBetweenEdges < 180:
      return index

  // Will never actually reach here unless code error:
  return -1
}

while listOfPoints.length > 2:
  pointIndex = getNextConvexPointIndex(listOfPoints)
  triangleAreaOfPoint = getTriangleArea(listOfPoints, pointIndex)
  totalArea += triangleAreaOfPoint
  listOfPoints.remove(pointIndex)
```

I don't have a mathematical proof at hand, but I'm pretty sure that taking any polygon, it's made up of convex triangles that can be found in the method I describe.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I'm almost sure this method does not work with not-convex polygons.

Comment: @Ripi2 Since you're always taking only a point that is convex in relation to the adjacent points, I'm pretty sure it is. You keep slicing off convex pieces from the original polygon until it's all gone.

Comment: Maybe, if you show how `getNextConvexPointIndex` fulfills.

Comment: @Ripi2 I do. There is a link to how to check if a point is in a convex polygon. Take *a* point you want to check, and use the code in the link with the point in question and *all other points of our polygon*.

Comment: @Ripi2 - found a better way, updating the question shortly

Comment: @Ripi2 Done. Got a nice way to find a point that is convex with relation to its neighbours.